# Why is this code threadsafe?

Tags: linux, multithreading, mutex

For this code it says that it is thread unsafe:

```
/* thread-unsafe function */
int increment_counter()
{
        static int counter = 0;

        counter++;
        return counter;
}
```

But for below code, it is said to be thread safe:

```
/* pseudo-code threadsafe function */
int increment_counter();
{
        static int counter = 0;
        static lock_type counter_lock = LOCK_INITIALIZER;

        pthread_mutex_lock(counter_lock);
        counter++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(counter_lock);
        return counter;
}
```

I cannot understand it. Could anyone explain more about it?

Comment: The idea is to have a consistent state for your `counter`. This is why it is "captured" during the change. Imagine that 2 threads see counter=0 and increment it at the same time => counter=1 (instead of 2), because both of them think that `counter=0` before `counter++`. So instead of having return 2, you'll have 1.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now, how to change your comment to be the answer?

Comment: Adding a mutex assures that no one else is incrementing that counter from some other part in the code. Mutex is like a round-robin assuring that only one user/process at the time uses that part of the code.